# Free Form Diagram of one block on top of another block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, contact-mechanics

I am having understanding the soln to this problem.

Here, FDM of Block A and Block B is drawn separately to split the problem. Now in Block B, i fail to understand why does N1 considered act downwards and why Weight of Block A is not acting on Block B.

[image]

Comment: I do not see a force R1 in the diagram. Perhaps you made a typing mistake. The weight of block A is acting on block B through N1: equal and opposite reactions.

Comment: Sry for typo. I corrected it. "The weight of block A is acting on block B through N1" - Can you please clarify? @JohnHoltz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now in Block B, why does N1 considered act downwards?

N1 is determined from the free body diagram (FBD) of block A. The direction is arbitrary, but it makes sense if N1 is pointed up on block A to counteract the weight. (If the arbitrary direction is wrong, then the solutions of the equations of equilibrium for block A will give a negative value for N1, and the negative value would indicate that the force is acting in the opposite direction.)

From Newton's third law (equal and opposite reactions), the force N1 is acting downward on block B because it is acting upward on block A.

> Why weight of Block A is not acting on Block B?

The effects of the weight of Block A **is** acting on Block B: it is in the force N1. The pulling force T offsets part of the weight of Block A. In other words, if T=0, then N1=WA, and the full weight of Block A is acting on Block B. If T were pointed straight up and T=WA, then T is supporting the full weight of Block A, N1=0, and none of the weight of Block A is acting on Block B.

Basically, you need to write the equations of static equilibrium for block A (sum of vertical forces = 0, sum of horizontal forces = 0), solve for the unknown values (N1 and F1), transfer those values to the FBD for Block B, write the equations of static equilibrium, and solve for P.